# I get a DexExeption when building project in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I receive this error while trying to build my project in Android Studio. I have seen other posts with similar errors, but none of which specifically give the Landroid/support/annotation/AnimRes; as the place or error. Please help, thank you very much.

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
/Users/ethanraymond/Install Programs/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140624/sdk/build-tools/21.1.2/dx --dex --no-optimize --output /Users/ethanraymond/Software Programming/Projects/Apps/Finger Dodge/Android/dev/FingerDodge/app/build/intermediates/dex/debug --input-list=/Users/ethanraymond/Software Programming/Projects/Apps/Finger Dodge/Android/dev/FingerDodge/app/build/intermediates/tmp/dex/debug/inputList.txt
Error Code:
2
Output:
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/annotation/AnimRes;
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
```

Comment: The solution will be the same as the other posts about duplication in the support library classes; the fact that it's choosing a different class in that package to complain about probably isn't relevant.